# How do I use/get the list element out of the namespace?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, function, namespaces

I'm trying to write a Python program that will take given list and return the average.

```
#program name: average.py, author: Leo

import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-lst", nargs='+', type=int, required=True)
xyz = parser.parse_args()

def GetAvg(xyz):
    total = 0
    for i in xyz:
        total = total + i

    finalAvg = total / len(xyz)
    return finalAvg

if __name__ == "__main__":
    GetAvg(xyz)
```

When I run it in my cmd prompt I run it as

```
python average.py -lst 4 5 7 3 2
```

However, I always get the error message: `'Namespace' object is not iterable`.

When I do a `print(xyz)` it returns `"Namespace(lst=[4, 5, 7, 3, 2])"`.

So my question is: 
How do I get this function to use the list within the namespace? -or- Do I use some other `argparse` function to accomplish this?

I apologize for any incorrect syntax or styling, first post on StackOverflow.

Comment: Try: `for i in xyz.lst: print(i)`

Comment: The list value in the `xyz` namespace can be referenced via `vars(xyz)['lst']`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parser returns the namespace with all arguments, you have to access the specific argument. Here is your program with a few commented changes:

```
import argparse


def get_avg(xyz):  # use pep8-style names (get_avg instead of GetAvg)
    total = sum(xyz)  # use predefined Python functions
    return total / len(xyz)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # put all of the main program here so that it is not executed 
    # if the function is called from elsewhere
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()  
    parser.add_argument("-lst", nargs='+', type=int, required=True)
    xyz = parser.parse_args().lst  # access the needed argument
    print(get_avg(xyz))
```